# getting a variable out of a function with module.exports but without a return

Tags: javascript

i am a bit lost:

I am trying to make a variable available in another function, since i do need the return for something else already. i thought i could just make the variable global available and import it in FileB, whats wrong and might there be a better way? thanks a lot

FileA:

```
const variableToPass = null;

module.exports = (env) => {
    variableToPass = env;

    const varA = require(`./FileB.js`); 
    const varB = doThis(varA, …doSomething());
    return varB;
};

module.exports = variableToPass;
```

FileB:

```
const variableToPass = require(‚./.FileA‘);

console.log(variableToPass);
```

it does log : `{ [Function] variableToPass: null }`

Comment: Globals are evil. Do not use globals if you can help it.

Comment: yes thats what i thought :-) but i have no clue how to pass the var to the file via require or similar inside the module.export in the env function

Comment: Your import is now a function with an `env` property, so it looks like it works, although I'm not sure you wanted to attach a property to a function.

Comment: yes the property is param i use in the function, but i would like to make the property available in fileB as well , wich i require in the function

Comment: So why not do `module.exports = { env: env, func: <your function> }`

Comment: Which variable do you need to make available where? Your code does lots of passing things around that I cannot quite track.

Comment: "*since i do need the return for something else already*" - what? why can't you just return both things?

Comment: i tried to clean it up, its a webpack config with different merges, as soon as ireturn something else it stops working.  sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems here.

1. `const env` defines a constant, so you can't change it
2. `(env) => {` masks it with a local variable of the same name, so you don't even try to change it
3. You never call that function anyway
4. `module.exports.env = env;` copies the **value** of `env` *at the time the statement is evaluated*, so even if you did change `env`, it wouldn't change the value of the exported property

Just export a sensible data structure which contains everything you need.

```
// called.js

var env = null;

function stuff() {
    env = 1;
    return 2;
}

function get_side_effect() {
    return env;
}

module.exports = {
    stuff: stuff,
    get_side_effect: get_side_effect   
};

// caller.js

const caller = require("caller");

var stuff = called.stuff();
var side_effect = called.get_side_effect();
console.log(stuff, side_effect);
```

or return a sensible data structure from your function:

```
// called.js

var env = null;

function stuff() {
    env = 1;
    return {
        value: 2,
        env: env
    };
}


module.exports = {
    stuff: stuff
};

// caller.js

const called = require("called");

var stuff = called.stuff();
console.log(stuff.value, stuff.env);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if this is not the best practice you can try to use getter and setter functions and export your whole class. in Addition the env must be a let not a const.

```
setEnv(){
  env = val;
}

getEnv(val){
   return env;
}
```

in FileB:

```
console.log(fileA.getEnv);
```